# MailChimp API 3.0 resources guide

Tags: mailchimp

We are working on building connectors for Mailchimp using one of our client tool.
We are referring  http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/ for mailchimp API 3.0 resource guide.

Few of the resources like template folders,campaign folders, content,send_checklist are newly added up to this guide. These were not present earlier whenever I did the  analysis of mailchimp API.

Is the guide contain complete list of resources of 3.0? Will it get Updated frequently?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at developer.mailchimp.com is complete, but things will be added to it as new features are added to the API.